# jQuery scrolling text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "a" element that I want to scroll left on hover. To do this I remove the first character and append it to the end of the string.

How can I continuously fire up the scroll function?

Mouse enters element -> scroll() is fired until mouse leaves the element or user clicks on it.

html:

```
<a href="foo.htm" class="scrollthis">this text scrolls on hover</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".scrollthis").hover(function(){
    scroll($(this));

});

function scroll(ele){

    var s = $(ele).text().substr(1)+$(ele).text().substr(0,1);
    $(ele).text(s);
}
```

Comment: i would add a space to the end of the text, else the first and last word get glued together.

Comment: btw: what's with all the marquee and scrolling text questions today? did i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` to call it repeatedly from mouseenter, then `clearInterval()` to stop it on mouseleave:

```
var intervalID;
$(".scrollthis").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
       scroll($this);
    }, 100);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
});
```

Note that you don't need to use `$(ele)` in your `scroll()` function because `ele` is already a jQuery object:

```
function scroll(ele){
    var s = ele.text().substr(1)+ele.text().substr(0,1);
    ele.text(s);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hTBZn/

You can make your `scroll()` function a bit neater if you use the callback syntax of the `.text()` method (or even move that one line directly into the `.hover` code):

```
function scroll(ele){
    ele.text(function(i,val) { return val.substr(1) + val.substr(0,1); });
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hTBZn/1/

Comment: @Engineer - It works as is with multiple elements here: http://jsfiddle.net/hTBZn/2/ - Assuming the elements with that class aren't nested there should only be one interval at a time, and given the OP asked specifically about an anchor element they shouldn't be nested. But it could be updated to store the interval id on the element itself using `.data()`.

Comment: Yes, with `.data()` implementation,it'll work for multiple elements.

Comment: @Engineer: `.data()` would allow better for future (as yet unknown) requirements, but my code as is works without it as per the fiddle in my previous comment. Regarding my assumption that the elements won't be nested, note that the `scroll()` function provided by the OP uses `.text()` and so pretty much confirms the assumption.

Comment: You notice about `.text()` correctly. But for not `poluting` the function's scope,using `.data()` could be more preferable.On the other hand we don't know the level of javascript skills of the OP.So by avoiding the complicated code, your answer might be applicable. +1 anyway.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Although the my approach seems to be not so good. Manipulating the string to simulate a scroll effect leads to a "not so smooth" effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code, you can [try it out as a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFEE6/)

```
function scroll(ele){
    var s = $(ele).text().substr(1)+$(ele).text().substr(0,1);
    $(ele).text(s);
}

scrollInterval = null;
function startScrolling(e) {
    if (!scrollInterval) {
        scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
            scroll(e)
        },100);
    }
}

function stopScrolling(e) {
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    scrollInterval = null;
}

$(".scrollthis").hover(function(){
    startScrolling($(this));
});

$(".scrollthis").mouseout(function(){
    stopScrolling($(this));
});

$(".scrollthis").mousedown(function(){
    stopScrolling($(this));
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
  div.container{
      width: 130px;
    }
    div.title-holder {
      width: 130px;
      height:20px;
      text-align:center;
      background: silver;
      overflow:hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    div.title-holder a {  
      position: relative;  
      white-space:nowrap;  
        left: 0px;
    }
    div.image{
        background: brown;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }​
```

**html**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-holder">
        <a href="somelink.html">long text that needs to scroll, long text that needs to scroll, long text that needs to scroll</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**js**

```
    $(function(){
var scroll_text;
$('div.container').hover(
    function () {
        var $elmt = $(this);
        scroll_text = setInterval(function(){scrollText($elmt);}, 5);
    },
    function () {
        clearInterval(scroll_text);
        $(this).find('div.title-holder a').css({
            left: 0
        });
    }
);

    var scrollText = function($elmt){
        var left = $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').position().left - 1;
        left = -left > $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').width() ? $elmt.find('div.title-holder').width() : left;
        $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').css({
            left: left
        });
    };

});​
```